# Session.add() does not work on SqlAlchemy(Python2.7)

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, addition

I'm using SqlAlchemy-1.0.9  and python 2.7.

So, when I try to add an object to a session, nothing happens and consequently the data is not inserted in the dataBase. I'm using mysql and oursql by the way.

Some of the code below:

First I create a function to make the "create engine" and etc... and I use it every time I want to create a session.

```
base = declarative_base()

engine = create_engine('mysql+oursql://root:toor@127.0.0.1/pandora', echo=True)

def sessionLoader():
    base.metadata.bind = engine
    DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = DBSession()
    return session
```

After that in my class I call the sessionLoader() method:

I create the object and so on and then use the add() method:

```
newEntity = Entity(name = 'John')

sessionLoader().add(newEntity)

sessionLoader().commit()
```

After that that no erros or exceptions displayed on the console.
But when I go to the DataBase and do some selects there are no data there.

To make a test I put the folowing piece of code:

```
print newEntity in sessionLoader()
```

it shows 'False' on the console.

So 'add()'is not doing the work it shoud do.

Any tips or help?

Answer (score 5):

Everytime you call `sessionLoader()` you are creating a new session. The code looks like you are creating the entity in one session and committing a different session.

Comment: Got it... I was doing it wrong calling the method after creating the instance..                      What I did to correct was:                                                                        Instead of calling the "sessionLoad()" method only after creating the entity I "instantiated"(like we do with classes) before doing the whole thing..

Comment: I used the modifications described in the answer I gave above ... Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

After I made my changes it became:

So it became:

```
session = sessionLoader()
newEntity = Entity(name = 'John')
session.add(newEntity)
session.commit()
```

Now it works!!